# Extra identity pool IDs in Cognito with Amplify Auth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

So I have a problem and have not been able to diagnose the issue, so I am reaching out to see if anyone has experienced anything similar to this in the past and could provide some hints so that I can debug.

**Here is the rundown...**
I have a serverless web application which use AWS Amplify Auth to enable the creation of user accounts through email and social (facebook and google for right now). When I log in (which I believe is the triggering action but can't confirm) a new identity ID is created in the identity pool. So, what I have ended up with is 3 users in the User Pool and about ~70 identity IDs in the identity pool.

I am not using the Amplify components as I am opting for a custom flow and creating my components. I have a feeling I am calling 'signup' somewhere twice and that may be why.

Comment: If you are certain 70 users have never registered (even for testing) then yes it seems like an issue with your code

Comment: Hi Ninad, yes I definitely think so...I am just wondering if anyone has ever seen this behavior before and knew what caused it or where to look. We are a small team of engineers so sometimes it's tough to get to the root cause of these odd issues.

Comment: I would take a look at the code dealing with sign up. I haven't read about this being an issue in cognito in any of the forums, so I don't think it's an issue with cognito itself.

Comment: I'll investigate further this week and post the solution I find including root cause, now that I have a few extra hours to dedicate to this.